# Random operator generator

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I'm trying to create a program that generates random arithmetic questions with random operators. I can randomly generate "+" and "-", but can't generate "*" or "/", because of their interesting type. Here is my code so far:

```
from random import randint

try:
    score = 0
    while 1:
        x1 = randint(0, 99)
        x2 = randint(0, 99)
        x3 = randint(0, 99)

        correctAnswer = x1 + x2 + x3
        correctAnswer = str(correctAnswer)

        print(str(x1)  + "+" + str(x2) + "+" + str(x3)) 
        yourAnswer = raw_input("Answer: " )

        if yourAnswer == correctAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong! Ans:" + str(correctAnswer))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Score:" + str(score))
```

How would I go about changing my code to implement a random operator generator for these arithmetic questions?

Comment: This isn't very clear. What would prevent you from replacing `+` by `*` in the above code? For quotients, if you want the final result to be an integer you could start with a random answer and then work backwards. In other words, if you want `a/b = c` pick random `c` and `b` and then calculate the `a` that works.

Comment: I think you could generate the expression string with the random operator characters then call eval() to get the correct answer

Comment: No John Coleman, I want random operators, not a permanent multiplier. I want an equal chance of any of the questions to contain a +, -, *, or /.

Comment: Pick them with equal chance then -- have the above code (suitably modified for different operators) conditionally called depending on your global choice. You still haven't explained in what way the "interesting type" of `*` prevents you from doing with `*` what you say that you know how to do with `+` and `-`

Comment: Thank you dsboger, you have the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got an answer in the comments, but I thought I might try encourage you to not use `eval`, it's generally regarded as a poor practice.

A great thing Python can do is you can actually import [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) as functions instead of having to use the characters. For example

```
from operator import mul
a = mul(2, 5)
b = 2 * 5
```

will result in both `a` and `b` being `10`.

Combine that with a reduction and some string formatting and your program can be a lot neater than `eval`ing strings.

```
from random import randint, choice
from operator import add, sub, mul

score = 0
try:
    while True:
        x1 = randint(0, 99)
        x2 = randint(0, 99)
        x3 = randint(0, 99)

        operator, operator_symbol = choice([
            (add, '+'),
            (sub, '-'),
            (mul, '*'),
        ])

        correct_answer = reduce(operator, [x1, x2, x3])

        print("{x1} {op} {x2} {op} {x3}".format(
            x1=x1,
            x2=x2,
            x3=x3,
            op=operator_symbol
        ))

        your_answer = raw_input("Answer: ")

        if your_answer == correct_answer:
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong! Ans: " + str(correct_answer))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Score:" + str(score))
```

This code is missing divide because with just randomly generating numbers, you're going to get `0` as the answer most times. You could use the factor generation idea that @JohnColeman had in their comment for that.